# A word describing liking a part of something but disliking its entirety

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

In a (not so?) recent episode of the most excellent QI, Mr Fry talked about a word which meant liking a part of something although not liking (detesting?) the whole entity; e.g. liking the martial music of Hitlers Germany but detesting the Nazi regime in its entirety.

Anyone know what the word is I am am looking for?

I have been searching the internet for some considerable time trying to get the answer but without success.

Grateful if someone can help.

Comment: I can only think of the phrase "[curate's egg](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curate%27s_egg)" which is a phrase not a word.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully: That's an excellent candidate that I believe would make a better answer than comment.

Comment: Ambiguous? As in _ambiguous feelings_?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word for feeling conflicting emotions simultaneously](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49476/word-for-feeling-conflicting-emotions-simultaneously). You're *ambivalent*, you have *mixed feelings*.

Comment: I think it is distinguishable from the earlier question which focused on ambivalence about one thing as opposed to distecting a thing into affectively conflicted parts.

Comment: A bit like how I like those bits of QI that don't involve Stephen Fry, I suppose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A saying for something that's good but also has a downside](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13944/a-saying-for-something-thats-good-but-also-has-a-downside)

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully    Your use of the word "describing" suggests that you are looking for an adjectival use, but your Nazi example suggests a verb.  I think it would be helpful to be more precise and specify how you want to use the term: adjectivally, nominally or verbally.  By the way, if you use the word "term" or "expression," then the very interesting "curate's egg" is not disqualified. However, because it functions nominally I suspect it isn't what you want.

Answer (score 3):

From what I know of Stephen Fry, it’s quite possible that, as donothingsuccessfully suggests, the phrase was *curate's egg*, from “True Humility”, a famous 1895 Punch cartoon by George DuMaurier:

[image: True Humility]

Bishop: “I’m afraid you've got a bad egg, Mr Jones”; Curate: “Oh, no, my Lord, I assure you that parts of it are excellent!”

The phrase denotes an effort to find some redeeming feature in something hopelessly bad.

Answer (score 1):

The term *[cherry-pick](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/cherry-pick?q=cherry-pick)* may come close, even if it is not dead-on

> 1 [with object] selectively choose (the most beneficial items) from what is available: *the company should buy the whole airline and not just cherry-pick its best assets*

This generally refers to selecting what is choice from among the dross. There is not necessarily a suggestion of *detesting* the remainder, just not thinking it is worthwhile.

It is more often used in connection with acquisition, but could be used with ideological selection, as in

> He didn't buy into Buddhism, he just *cherry-picked* the feelgood parts.